# NUCLEO F401RE sending wrong data via UART to nRF DK board

Tags: c, uart, hal, nucleo, nrf52

I'm trying to send data from the NUCLEO board to an nRF 52840 DK via UART. The problem is that what ever I send is recived incorrectly. For example when I send the value 3 I receive 32. I'm not sure what the issue is.

This the the NUCLEO Code
'''

```
  uint8_t cr = 3;
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, cr, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

'''

And the code for the nRF DK. From *peripheral/uart* example code

'''

```
   uint8_t cr;
   while (app_uart_get(&cr) != NRF_SUCCESS); 
   while (app_uart_put(cr) != NRF_SUCCESS);
   printf("BLE recived %u\r\n",cr);
```

'''

Both have a Baud Rate of 115200

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: That HAL call looks very suspicious.  You sure that it takes a char argument and not char* ?

Comment: ....else what is the '1' for??

Comment: how many stop bits?  does it include the parity bit?  how many data bits?   These details have to be exactly the same on both ends of the communication

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.